# How to enable lubuntu-12.10-alternate-amd64.iso to PXE network install the graphical desktop?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, desktop-environments, preseed, pxe

I have successfully used lubuntu-12.10-alternate-amd64.iso to PXE network install a server.  But so far, I have not been able to get the desktop login installed regardless what I put in in the preseed file:

1. `tasksel tasksel/first multiselect lubuntu-desktop`
2. `d-i pkgsel/include string lubuntu-desktop`

Neither triggered a desktop UI install.  The logs in the `/var/log/installer` subdirectory do not give me any clue either.

I have got around this "issue" by running a `preseed/late_command` or use the iso's content in conjunction with a local repository mirror.

BTW, I have noticed that the `Packages.gz` in the iso's `universe/debian-installer/binary-amd64` doesn't have any content. Replacing it with the one in the `universe/binary-amd64` and adding a Release file doesn't result a graphical UI install either.  How can I "fix" the iso's content so that I can use it for a desktop install with both a burned CD and PXE network boot?

Answer (score 1):

Once you set up the TFTP server it is really straightforward with any ***?*-ubuntu**'s 12.10: two commands on the shell.
Just bind/mount your TFTP server web root to the subfolder `./install/netboot` in the *Alternate* ISO image of the OS.

If you have correctly setup Linux-based TFTP server, then:

- Let `/srv/tftp` be your TFTP webroot
- Let `/path_to_image/Lubuntu.iso` be your *?*-ubuntu OS image file;

then just type in (as root):

```
mkdir /mnt/tmp
mount -oro,loop,iso9660 /path_to_image/Lubuntu.iso /mnt/tmp
mount --bind /mnt/tmp/install/netboot /srv/tftp
```

Reboot your client and it's done to receive the ?ubuntu OS via PXE.